# Website navigation: showing/hiding specific divs on the new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

new to dynamic web design so please bear with me. I am designing a website to share videos with all friends that we make on a day out etc.

I will have the video names (may be with a thumbnail from the video) on my homepage of the website. When they wish to see a video, they click on the title/thumbnail of that video on the homepage. A new page then opens (that contains all my videos) so their chosen video is played.

But when this video is played, all they can see is just that particular video on the newly opened page and not the rest of the videos. So I was thinking of achieving this by hiding all the divs that contain videos except for the one that has their selected video.

If I had on the home page then I could achieve this by linking to a particular div with its ID. And could target this div specifically to display and hide the rest with something like this:

```
$(this).findElementById('href');
```

But as the videos will be on a separate page, so I am not sure how to keep track of the div ID that has been clicked on from the previous page.

Your help will be greatly appreciated guys, thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd approach this slightly differently. List all your videos on your home page, then when they click on a video, pass the ID of that video to the next page (if possible) - then that page can just deal with the one video. 

Like YouTube... - If you're not using a database then you can use filename to still achieve this

Comment: I agree with Michael, just pass the ID of the video to the new page, for example: yoursite/view?id=23 or yoursite/view/23 (if you're using a RESTFUL API).

A different solution, and one that I would recommend is have a lightbox pop up and play the video.

Comment: Thank you guys @MichaelBellamy and zsawaf, this actually seems a better approach, would you be able to direct to me some link where I can probably learn a bit more about this kind of set up? As asking you for details may be a bit too much for your valueable time. Because I am not sure how to go about doing this right from here since I have recently started learning databases from phpmyadmin.

Comment: Well you're already on the right tracks if you are getting the data stored within your database. Once it's in there you can simply get all the videos for your home page using a query and then when you click on a video go get that specific video link from the database. If that doesn't help I'd suggest looking at either YouTube or PluralSight at get yourself trained up with MySQL & possibly PHP etc.

Comment: That helps alot, at least now on a higher level I know how it would work and I would definitely improve my MySQL and PHP skills to get it to work practically. Many thanks once again @MichaelBellamy I greatly appreciate your help.